# Legend entries for different line types in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this xts with a time series that I want to plot with recession shading using ggplot2:

```
time_series <- structure(c(0.114371630096418, 0.0959437177384127, 0.0892187992740256, 
0.0970998619801513, 0.126570281457749, 0.152017434450243, 0.195226296492682, 
0.195226296492682, 0.240935556451006, 0.226439918555576, 0.220381548212407, 
0.184229872903372, 0.208547731106556, 0.232591227902563, 0.222390611713699, 
0.168474695231925, 0.180651769489803, 0.216394789725435, 0.236743172952677, 
0.224410081456199, 0.24944010021399, 0.255921698957159, 0.280418001317228, 
0.260291087808842, 0.243046794567485, 0.216394789725435, 0.222390611713699, 
0.173627348371412, 0.212450094101026, 0.247299117394844, 0.247299117394844, 
0.243046794567485, 0.296576006791088, 0.195226296492682, 0.0739492075758969, 
0.0599529146786092, 0.0545230693645596, 0.0376790633800645, 0.0310087841277313, 
0.0245579879837868, 0.0474493761315668, 0.0947977293359985, 0.113069744578606, 
0.126570281457749, 0.123784095774292, 0.109227635573913, 0.101826721850442, 
0.110497775611901, 0.113069744578606, 0.07879990317384, 0.118341214689216, 
0.109227635573913, 0.129399853193971, 0.197097061597578, 0.228480082977696, 
0.24944010021399, 0.289598980032393, 0.251590894137366, 0.21838292868743, 
0.145744037351592, 0.129399853193971, 0.127979634360533, 0.0591522546091451, 
0.0666671990930106, 0.0758613710881861, 0.0947977293359985, 0.0675458780275329, 
0.0702356462017933, 0.067545878027533, 0.0666671990930107, 0.0903145795070023, 
0.0914203233167599, 0.0768314638658693, 0.083887928052527, 0.0711503103447975, 
0.0599529146786092, 0.0624058796726778, 0.0583600050264987, 0.0649364078311387, 
0.0797983411381213, 0.0797983411381213, 0.0903145795070023, 0.0959437177384127, 
0.107968019559137, 0.121041132459971, 0.111778469059525, 0.111778469059525, 
0.123784095774292, 0.114371630096418, 0.109227635573913, 0.110497775611901, 
0.123784095774292, 0.138150318240886, 0.148858653000689, 0.136664548643223, 
0.130830956316472, 0.126570281457749, 0.136664548643223, 0.136664548643223, 
0.16175910086637, 0.189679070866325, 0.186035349455969, 0.193366361975197, 
0.204687952218995, 0.202774105415267, 0.195226296492682, 0.200870990685662, 
0.189679070866325, 0.175366949956961, 0.182435341187907, 0.18785175456929, 
0.180651769489803, 0.18785175456929, 0.191517279865218, 0.200870990685662, 
0.222390611713699, 0.258101598840969, 0.24944010021399, 0.271380287723942, 
0.271380287723942, 0.273626046782979, 0.262490107523433, 0.243046794567485, 
0.25375144536458, 0.243046794567485, 0.251590894137366, 0.262490107523433, 
0.25375144536458, 0.280418001317228, 0.332558046369618, 0.294241783594681, 
0.271380287723942, 0.305996593613646, 0.303629048682681, 0.264698598520289, 
0.284990860254423, 0.275880963018297, 0.385570877920714, 0.424862883042023, 
0.377837808330227, 0.367603218284351, 0.372709280167838, 0.320369785169131, 
0.271380287723942, 0.177117561413446, 0.103034183203958, 0.0778109592512763, 
0.144203274777203, 0.135189742076843, 0.155220422304151, 0.148858653000689, 
0.133725884562701, 0.180651769489803, 0.21838292868743, 0.208547731106556, 
0.210493604879707, 0.275880963018297, 0.287290548201947, 0.289598980032393, 
0.291916083075709, 0.260291087808842, 0.273626046782979, 0.282699987786792, 
0.278144970279619, 0.320369785169131, 0.362520453660103, 0.320369785169131, 
0.271380287723942, 0.32279252448619, 0.271380287723942, 0.305996593613646, 
0.409032789024476, 0.411661592996846, 0.320369785169131, 0.31314770131078, 
0.362520453660103, 0.380410234322597, 0.357461804985005, 0.31075600145678, 
0.236743172952677, 0.155220422304151, 0.126570281457749, 0.114371630096418, 
0.135189742076843, 0.119685804438398, 0.100629593548148, 0.083887928052527, 
0.0702356462017934, 0.0739492075758969, 0.0508884379854992, 0.0202450317854657, 
0.0234132440327757, 0.0399527266613274, 0.0261570516123136, 0.053045315508087, 
0.0936618594829083, 0.0632407023912572, 0.0808063182134509, 0.07879990317384, 
0.067545878027533, 0.0429502764603963, 0.0155071737758071, 0.00897916213950511, 
0.022675296201573, 0.0180392981373203, 0.0192731865997715, 0.0282774247339051, 
0.0314845776287238, 0.028718227137715, 0.044834364121709, 0.0552740582232772, 
0.0758613710881861, 0.0982661987491518, 0.129399853193971, 0.130830956316472, 
0.200870990685662, 0.243046794567485, 0.226439918555577, 0.411661592996846, 
0.569703735802906, 0.669776038653489, 0.652459280159517, 0.448829054350419, 
0.62716710778886, 0.524194860333282, 0.543006519506481, 0.377837808330227, 
0.534953696514431, 0.553715641107007, 0.508025930467615, 0.430167966199233, 
0.275880963018297, 0.580300983498286, 0.342438549069109, 0.236743172952677, 
0.287290548201947, 0.271380287723943, 0.104252011131161, 0.044834364121709, 
0.0265701491262988, 0.0142370064140275, 0.00983268806341939, 
0.0168734025275819, 0.0423366535500467, 0.0405382337008727, 0.0376790633800645, 
0.0291647283830858, 0.0155071737758071, 0.0157725584091764, 0.0091444799348236, 
0.00849881541590587, 0.0117544105368067, 0.0123911233065345, 
0.0123911233065345, 0.0189581766709391, 0.0147338960773301, 0.0139940213595224, 
0.0171586641628859, 0.0177415660048298, 0.0163150300941167, 0.0168734025275819, 
0.0149878862996999, 0.0119634192702049, 0.00931245631566063, 
0.00983268806341939, 0.017448036713583, 0.0257493384307016, 0.0310087841277313, 
0.0435710658693309, 0.0730070429509751, 0.0903145795070023, 0.0778109592512763, 
0.0649364078311387, 0.0739492075758969, 0.0684334791681454, 0.0545230693645596, 
0.0467844340529523, 0.0417301421309808, 0.0560331930253787, 0.064084194751024, 
0.0936618594829083, 0.210493604879707, 0.195226296492682, 0.296576006791088, 
0.354941776511928, 0.401171341556576, 0.393349704836979, 0.430167966199233, 
0.409032789024476, 0.430167966199232, 0.375270788369628, 0.411661592996846, 
0.464916510200114, 0.58294153488193, 0.700967941866677, 0.637357059200518, 
0.756850963848194, 0.652459280159517, 0.454183522899264, 0.891971372881761, 
0.773461763064138, 0.0666671990930107, 0.012175643652176, 0.028718227137715, 
0.0399527266613274, 0.104252011131161, 0.305996593613646, 0.614304217893127, 
0.915014692542477, 0.891971372881761, 0.746143937473896, 0.3985595567757, 
0.339957965624268, 0.857252823500678, 0.667323301955971, 0.513418354056404, 
0.486451424792063, 0.200870990685662, 0.0657973924375173, 0.016592206260383, 
0.00914447993482359, 0.023789731827192, 0.144203274777204, 0.111778469059525, 
0.113069744578606, 0.0730070429509752, 0.048801966876946, 0.0147338960773301, 
0.000361625022606035, 0.00032761959829567, 0.00489975205353219, 
0.0180392981373203, 0.0147338960773301, 0.01473389607733, 0.0144836171004844, 
0.0300750395672853, 0.028718227137715, 0.0287182271377149, 0.0349866890772889, 
0.0241712962183924, 0.0171586641628859, 0.0135187590047452, 0.00865636405338004, 
0.00819125042015333, 0.00983268806341939, 0.0109497504288359, 
0.0113458830643735, 0.0103781241326835, 0.00804116758132086, 
0.00225752368890396, 0.00178352822268941, 0.0045288518188473, 
0.0261570516123136, 0.0305389559691254, 0.0199165663284152, 0.00774823734538058, 
0.00302474867123215, 0.00207333962398429, 0.0045288518188473, 
0.00370894249323598, 0.00278453995677958, 0.00349038621651574, 
0.00480457359204027, 0.00461914780374578, 0.00499660713065199, 
0.00426734536349438, 0.00618003204342799, 0.0163150300941168, 
0.0300750395672853, 0.0319663901892977, 0.0632407023912572, 0.106718897466548, 
0.104252011131161, 0.0702356462017934, 0.067545878027533, 0.07879990317384, 
0.0632407023912572, 0.0265701491262988, 0.0261570516123136, 0.0441990767676171, 
0.0684334791681453, 0.0624058796726778, 0.0615796752526519, 0.0615796752526519, 
0.0212581098002395, 0.00789350737832702, 0.0117544105368067, 
0.0111462866235445, 0.0119634192702049, 0.00692503145842083, 
0.00335118085573927, 0.00519544753190765, 0.00471104699817386, 
0.00931245631566063, 0.016041829043891, 0.0130574947558983, 0.010193451291651, 
0.00983268806341939, 0.0186475566919186, 0.0230417822723115, 
0.0282774247339051, 0.0552740582232772, 0.0808063182134507, 0.109227635573913, 
0.130830956316473, 0.165094793320405, 0.197097061597577, 0.216394789725435, 
0.218382928687431, 0.238834333218926, 0.305996593613647, 0.303629048682681, 
0.287290548201947, 0.236743172952678, 0.251590894137366, 0.294241783594681, 
0.287290548201947, 0.210493604879707, 0.180651769489803, 0.18785175456929, 
0.133725884562701, 0.133725884562701, 0.177117561413446, 0.160107841199451, 
0.0970998619801513, 0.0730070429509751, 0.0711503103447975, 0.0936618594829083, 
0.0925360702974724, 0.0461269878943002, 0.043571065869331, 0.0282774247339052, 
0.0209157549361006, 0.0144836171004844, 0.012175643652176, 0.0126098981650079, 
0.0155071737758071, 0.0195926339188615, 0.0163150300941167, 0.00931245631566063, 
0.00692503145842083, 0.00461914780374578, 0.00267101154354514, 
0.00267101154354514, 0.0016349685458251, 0.00153104564798499, 
0.00216365539384172, 0.00202947675674532, 0.00290240458251202, 
0.0026158296680259, 0.00163496854582511, 0.00159963439461944, 
0.00240525470283456, 0.00216365539384172, 0.00378447675037312, 
0.00679560942667333, 0.0059479743582656, 0.00618003204342799, 
0.00881646828873009, 0.0109497504288359, 0.0132863978837774, 
0.0202450317854657, 0.023789731827192, 0.0142370064140276, 0.012175643652176, 
0.0109497504288359, 0.0119634192702049, 0.00746473946977845, 
0.00410059267149509, 0.00666832889635784, 0.00774823734538059, 
0.00760532532547936, 0.0111462866235445, 0.00965652495842374, 
0.0105657067908168, 0.0130574947558982, 0.0278422683267197, 0.0344676274659451, 
0.0583600050264987, 0.07879990317384, 0.0849345031971771, 0.142673531430952, 
0.186035349455969, 0.158467641457884, 0.123784095774292, 0.148858653000689, 
0.175366949956961, 0.210493604879707, 0.210493604879707, 0.195226296492682, 
0.139647063946859, 0.0959437177384128, 0.0702356462017934, 0.0568005270542868, 
0.0494897247676012, 0.0568005270542869, 0.067545878027533, 0.0552740582232772, 
0.0720740931736916, 0.113069744578606, 0.0870569684223534, 0.0711503103447975, 
0.084934503197177, 0.0711503103447975, 0.0560331930253787, 0.0615796752526519, 
0.0702356462017933, 0.113069744578606, 0.114371630096418, 0.101826721850442, 
0.127979634360533, 0.178879171897708, 0.195226296492682, 0.224410081456199, 
0.228480082977696, 0.200870990685662, 0.18785175456929, 0.195226296492682, 
0.220381548212408, 0.224410081456199, 0.236743172952678, 0.289598980032394, 
0.210493604879707, 0.240935556451006, 0.275880963018297, 0.24944010021399, 
0.212450094101026, 0.170181212833596, 0.153613400649759, 0.130830956316472, 
0.0936618594829083, 0.104252011131161, 0.106718897466548, 0.104252011131161, 
0.103034183203958, 0.142673531430952, 0.12517177527814, 0.0925360702974724, 
0.141154797927666, 0.210493604879707, 0.260291087808842, 0.195226296492682, 
0.243046794567485, 0.315547288068903, 0.403787550149879, 0.388158880538109, 
0.432825305230518, 0.454183522899265, 0.475675085074895, 0.335017621220478, 
0.284990860254423, 0.230530533538244, 0.100629593548148, 0.053045315508087, 
0.0515995019735965, 0.0560331930253787, 0.0657973924375174, 0.0334484812527442, 
0.0202450317854657, 0.0107562364056755, 0.00328346717689721, 
0.00335118085573926, 0.00499660713065199, 0.00272724253096127, 
0.00267101154354514, 0.00308764631062019, 0.00461914780374579, 
0.00760532532547935, 0.0137546195766821, 0.0265701491262988, 
0.021957050868906, 0.0100116514402685, 0.00965652495842373, 0.00897916213950511, 
0.0117544105368067, 0.0128320084664356, 0.00983268806341939, 
0.017448036713583, 0.0202450317854657, 0.00618003204342799, 0.00267101154354514, 
0.00378447675037312, 0.00349038621651573, 0.00349038621651573, 
0.00349038621651573, 0.00426734536349438, 0.0054012984329513, 
0.00881646828873009, 0.00321698646357347, 0.00174527932766829, 
0.00290240458251202, 0.00519544753190763, 0.0103781241326835, 
0.0180392981373204, 0.022675296201573, 0.0319663901892976, 0.036044061663024, 
0.044834364121709, 0.0640841947510241, 0.0537801729968821, 0.0702356462017933, 
0.0970998619801513, 0.132272961228319, 0.142673531430952, 0.165094793320405, 
0.17189876642844, 0.177117561413446, 0.193366361975197, 0.208547731106556, 
0.294241783594681, 0.303629048682681, 0.287290548201947, 0.247299117394844, 
0.247299117394844, 0.262490107523433, 0.303629048682681, 0.357461804985005, 
0.359988064151646, 0.385570877920713, 0.424862883042023, 0.411661592996846, 
0.393349704836979, 0.416931000090244, 0.435485685576825, 0.382987959902319, 
0.332558046369619, 0.226439918555577, 0.294241783594681, 0.230530533538244, 
0.198978634349745, 0.198978634349745, 0.155220422304151, 0.122407222068081, 
0.138150318240886, 0.0649364078311387, 0.0261570516123136, 0.0209157549361005, 
0.0305389559691255, 0.0265701491262988, 0.0212581098002395, 0.0296169814738128, 
0.0157725584091764, 0.00550691770618706, 0.00370894249323598, 
0.0209157549361005, 0.0209157549361005, 0.0155071737758071, 0.0144836171004845, 
0.0109497504288359, 0.00583486918312572, 0.00245640885992405, 
0.00342014721445066, 0.00315171924869831, 0.00418322582811124, 
0.00386138726925095, 0.00363476326134048, 0.00245640885992405, 
0.00186232248266333, 0.00225752368890396, 0.00225752368890396, 
0.00178352822268941, 0.00435297410001227, 0.00618003204342799, 
0.00948312623508185, 0.0163150300941167, 0.017448036713583, 0.0202450317854657, 
0.0142370064140276, 0.0054012984329513, 0.0045288518188473, 0.00296300759408847, 
0.0039396955463455, 0.00328346717689721, 0.00561436804204923, 
0.00774823734538059, 0.00774823734538059, 0.0249498581112422, 
0.0399527266613274, 0.0314845776287238, 0.0382373343607509, 0.0399527266613274, 
0.0417301421309807, 0.0454769828658851, 0.0334484812527442, 0.0399527266613274, 
0.0575761134153295, 0.0730070429509751, 0.0828510677361414, 0.0684334791681454, 
0.0657973924375174, 0.0624058796726778, 0.0702356462017933, 0.0624058796726778, 
0.0481218688553975, 0.0454769828658851, 0.0461269878943002, 0.0583600050264987, 
0.044834364121709, 0.0261570516123136, 0.0163150300941167, 0.0123911233065345, 
0.0105657067908168, 0.0155071737758071, 0.0135187590047452, 0.00983268806341939, 
0.0100116514402685, 0.0132863978837774, 0.0130574947558982, 0.0128320084664356, 
0.016592206260383, 0.0157725584091764, 0.0171586641628858, 0.0209157549361005, 
0.0171586641628859, 0.0249498581112422, 0.023789731827192, 0.0291647283830858, 
0.0474493761315668, 0.0405382337008727, 0.0376790633800645, 0.0429502764603963, 
0.0291647283830858, 0.022675296201573, 0.0245579879837868, 0.032948287981271, 
0.0305389559691255, 0.0355121489580039, 0.0310087841277313, 0.0376790633800645, 
0.048801966876946, 0.07879990317384, 0.0666671990930106, 0.0684334791681453, 
0.0720740931736916, 0.0892187992740256, 0.109227635573913, 0.101826721850442, 
0.0925360702974724, 0.0828510677361414, 0.0591522546091451, 0.0393741110709996, 
0.0429502764603963, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), class = c("xts", "zoo"
), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "yearmon", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(-465609600, 
-463017600, -460339200, -457747200, -455068800, -452390400, -449798400, 
-447120000, -444528000, -441849600, -439171200, -436665600, -433987200, 
-431395200, -428716800, -426124800, -423446400, -420768000, -418176000, 
-415497600, -412905600, -410227200, -407548800, -405129600, -402451200, 
-399859200, -397180800, -394588800, -391910400, -389232000, -386640000, 
-383961600, -381369600, -378691200, -376012800, -373593600, -370915200, 
-368323200, -365644800, -363052800, -360374400, -357696000, -355104000, 
-352425600, -349833600, -347155200, -344476800, -342057600, -339379200, 
-336787200, -334108800, -331516800, -328838400, -326160000, -323568000, 
-320889600, -318297600, -315619200, -312940800, -310435200, -307756800, 
-305164800, -302486400, -299894400, -297216000, -294537600, -291945600, 
-289267200, -286675200, -283996800, -281318400, -278899200, -276220800, 
-273628800, -270950400, -268358400, -265680000, -263001600, -260409600, 
-257731200, -255139200, -252460800, -249782400, -247363200, -244684800, 
-242092800, -239414400, -236822400, -234144000, -231465600, -228873600, 
-226195200, -223603200, -220924800, -218246400, -215827200, -213148800, 
-210556800, -207878400, -205286400, -202608000, -199929600, -197337600, 
-194659200, -192067200, -189388800, -186710400, -184204800, -181526400, 
-178934400, -176256000, -173664000, -170985600, -168307200, -165715200, 
-163036800, -160444800, -157766400, -155088000, -152668800, -149990400, 
-147398400, -144720000, -142128000, -139449600, -136771200, -134179200, 
-131500800, -128908800, -126230400, -123552000, -121132800, -118454400, 
-115862400, -113184000, -110592000, -107913600, -105235200, -102643200, 
-99964800, -97372800, -94694400, -92016000, -89596800, -86918400, 
-84326400, -81648000, -79056000, -76377600, -73699200, -71107200, 
-68428800, -65836800, -63158400, -60480000, -57974400, -55296000, 
-52704000, -50025600, -47433600, -44755200, -42076800, -39484800, 
-36806400, -34214400, -31536000, -28857600, -26438400, -23760000, 
-21168000, -18489600, -15897600, -13219200, -10540800, -7948800, 
-5270400, -2678400, 0, 2678400, 5097600, 7776000, 10368000, 13046400, 
15638400, 18316800, 20995200, 23587200, 26265600, 28857600, 31536000, 
34214400, 36633600, 39312000, 41904000, 44582400, 47174400, 49852800, 
52531200, 55123200, 57801600, 60393600, 63072000, 65750400, 68256000, 
70934400, 73526400, 76204800, 78796800, 81475200, 84153600, 86745600, 
89424000, 92016000, 94694400, 97372800, 99792000, 102470400, 
105062400, 107740800, 110332800, 113011200, 115689600, 118281600, 
120960000, 123552000, 126230400, 128908800, 131328000, 134006400, 
136598400, 139276800, 141868800, 144547200, 147225600, 149817600, 
152496000, 155088000, 157766400, 160444800, 162864000, 165542400, 
168134400, 170812800, 173404800, 176083200, 178761600, 181353600, 
184032000, 186624000, 189302400, 191980800, 194486400, 197164800, 
199756800, 202435200, 205027200, 207705600, 210384000, 212976000, 
215654400, 218246400, 220924800, 223603200, 226022400, 228700800, 
231292800, 233971200, 236563200, 239241600, 241920000, 244512000, 
247190400, 249782400, 252460800, 255139200, 257558400, 260236800, 
262828800, 265507200, 268099200, 270777600, 273456000, 276048000, 
278726400, 281318400, 283996800, 286675200, 289094400, 291772800, 
294364800, 297043200, 299635200, 302313600, 304992000, 307584000, 
310262400, 312854400, 315532800, 318211200, 320716800, 323395200, 
325987200, 328665600, 331257600, 333936000, 336614400, 339206400, 
341884800, 344476800, 347155200, 349833600, 352252800, 354931200, 
357523200, 360201600, 362793600, 365472000, 368150400, 370742400, 
373420800, 376012800, 378691200, 381369600, 383788800, 386467200, 
389059200, 391737600, 394329600, 397008000, 399686400, 402278400, 
404956800, 407548800, 410227200, 412905600, 415324800, 418003200, 
420595200, 423273600, 425865600, 428544000, 431222400, 433814400, 
436492800, 439084800, 441763200, 444441600, 446947200, 449625600, 
452217600, 454896000, 457488000, 460166400, 462844800, 465436800, 
468115200, 470707200, 473385600, 476064000, 478483200, 481161600, 
483753600, 486432000, 489024000, 491702400, 494380800, 496972800, 
499651200, 502243200, 504921600, 507600000, 510019200, 512697600, 
515289600, 517968000, 520560000, 523238400, 525916800, 528508800, 
531187200, 533779200, 536457600, 539136000, 541555200, 544233600, 
546825600, 549504000, 552096000, 554774400, 557452800, 560044800, 
562723200, 565315200, 567993600, 570672000, 573177600, 575856000, 
578448000, 581126400, 583718400, 586396800, 589075200, 591667200, 
594345600, 596937600, 599616000, 602294400, 604713600, 607392000, 
609984000, 612662400, 615254400, 617932800, 620611200, 623203200, 
625881600, 628473600, 631152000, 633830400, 636249600, 638928000, 
641520000, 644198400, 646790400, 649468800, 652147200, 654739200, 
657417600, 660009600, 662688000, 665366400, 667785600, 670464000, 
673056000, 675734400, 678326400, 681004800, 683683200, 686275200, 
688953600, 691545600, 694224000, 696902400, 699408000, 702086400, 
704678400, 707356800, 709948800, 712627200, 715305600, 717897600, 
720576000, 723168000, 725846400, 728524800, 730944000, 733622400, 
736214400, 738892800, 741484800, 744163200, 746841600, 749433600, 
752112000, 754704000, 757382400, 760060800, 762480000, 765158400, 
767750400, 770428800, 773020800, 775699200, 778377600, 780969600, 
783648000, 786240000, 788918400, 791596800, 794016000, 796694400, 
799286400, 801964800, 804556800, 807235200, 809913600, 812505600, 
815184000, 817776000, 820454400, 823132800, 825638400, 828316800, 
830908800, 833587200, 836179200, 838857600, 841536000, 844128000, 
846806400, 849398400, 852076800, 854755200, 857174400, 859852800, 
862444800, 865123200, 867715200, 870393600, 873072000, 875664000, 
878342400, 880934400, 883612800, 886291200, 888710400, 891388800, 
893980800, 896659200, 899251200, 901929600, 904608000, 907200000, 
909878400, 912470400, 915148800, 917827200, 920246400, 922924800, 
925516800, 928195200, 930787200, 933465600, 936144000, 938736000, 
941414400, 944006400, 946684800, 949363200, 951868800, 954547200, 
957139200, 959817600, 962409600, 965088000, 967766400, 970358400, 
973036800, 975628800, 978307200, 980985600, 983404800, 986083200, 
988675200, 991353600, 993945600, 996624000, 999302400, 1001894400, 
1004572800, 1007164800, 1009843200, 1012521600, 1014940800, 1017619200, 
1020211200, 1022889600, 1025481600, 1028160000, 1030838400, 1033430400, 
1036108800, 1038700800, 1041379200, 1044057600, 1046476800, 1049155200, 
1051747200, 1054425600, 1057017600, 1059696000, 1062374400, 1064966400, 
1067644800, 1070236800, 1072915200, 1075593600, 1078099200, 1080777600, 
1083369600, 1086048000, 1088640000, 1091318400, 1093996800, 1096588800, 
1099267200, 1101859200, 1104537600, 1107216000, 1109635200, 1112313600, 
1114905600, 1117584000, 1120176000, 1122854400, 1125532800, 1128124800, 
1130803200, 1133395200, 1136073600, 1138752000, 1141171200, 1143849600, 
1146441600, 1149120000, 1151712000, 1154390400, 1157068800, 1159660800, 
1162339200, 1164931200, 1167609600, 1170288000, 1172707200, 1175385600, 
1177977600, 1180656000, 1183248000, 1185926400, 1188604800, 1191196800, 
1193875200, 1196467200, 1199145600, 1201824000, 1204329600, 1207008000, 
1209600000, 1212278400, 1214870400, 1217548800, 1220227200, 1222819200, 
1225497600, 1228089600, 1230768000, 1233446400, 1235865600, 1238544000, 
1241136000, 1243814400, 1246406400, 1249084800, 1251763200, 1254355200, 
1257033600, 1259625600, 1262304000, 1264982400, 1267401600, 1270080000, 
1272672000, 1275350400, 1277942400, 1280620800, 1283299200, 1285891200, 
1288569600, 1291161600, 1293840000, 1296518400, 1298937600, 1301616000, 
1304208000, 1306886400, 1309478400, 1312156800, 1314835200, 1317427200, 
1320105600, 1322697600, 1325376000, 1328054400, 1330560000, 1333238400, 
1335830400, 1338508800, 1341100800, 1343779200, 1346457600, 1349049600, 
1351728000, 1354320000, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1362096000, 1364774400, 
1367366400, 1370044800, 1372636800, 1375315200, 1377993600, 1380585600, 
1383264000, 1385856000, 1388534400, 1391212800, 1393632000, 1396310400, 
1398902400, 1401580800, 1404172800, 1406851200, 1409529600, 1412121600, 
1414800000, 1417392000, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400, 
1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600, 
1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 1459468800, 
1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 1475280000, 
1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(742L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("predict_rec", "in_sample")))
```

For the recession shading I have the following data frame with recession start and end dates:

```
recession_dates <- structure(list(start = structure(c(-4505, -3532, 0, 1430, 3683, 
4230, 7517, 11413, 13879), class = "Date"), end = structure(c(-4263, 
-3228, 334, 1916, 3865, 4717, 7760, 11657, 14426), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

As you can see, the data I want to plot consists on an in-sample and an out-of-sample part, which I want tot plot with different line types. Using this code I pieced together from some other answer got pretty far, but tbh I don't really understand how the legend is constructed from this code.

```
time_series %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_rect(data = recession_dates, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "NBER recession"), alpha = 0.5, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = "grey50", guide = guide_legend(alpha = 0.5, keyheight = unit(3, "mm"))) +
    geom_line(data = subset(time_series, in_sample == 1), aes(x = Index, y = data, lty = "In-sample"), color = "black", size = 0.7) +
    geom_line(data = subset(time_series, in_sample == 0), aes(x = Index, y = data, lty = "Out-of-sample"), linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 0.7) +
    scale_linetype(name = "", guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill=NA), keyheight = unit(3, "mm")))
```

[image: plot]

I know that normally you would only use one `geom_line()` and add something like `group = in_sample` or `linetype = in_sample` to the `aes()` to automatically create the legend for the different line types, but this gave me the error:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

So, my question is: how can I add a separate legend entry for the dashed line to my legend?

EDIT: any suggestions on how to improve/cleanup the `ggplot` code is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
ggplot(time_series, aes(x = Index, y = predict_rec)) +
  geom_line(aes(lty = factor(in_sample)), size = 0.7) +
  geom_rect(data = recession_dates, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "NBER recession"), alpha = 0.5, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(NULL, values = c("dashed", "solid"), labels = c("Out-of-sample", "In-sample")) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = "grey50") +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(3, "mm")) + ylab("Name") + xlab(NULL)
```

[image]

I introduced many changes, mostly to simplify the code. As for the error, the issue was that `in_sample` is a numeric variable while we need a factor. Some other comments:

- Instead of repeating, say, `keyheight = unit(3, "mm")`, we can mention it just once in `theme`.
- The two `geom_line` were identical except for the line type. We can use just one `geom_line` with `aes(lty = factor(in_sample))` and then set the values with `scale_linetype_manual`.
- `"black"` is already the default color unless we use a color aesthetic.
- Since `geom_rect` has `inherit.aes = FALSE`, we can specify `x = Index, y = data` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped me to understand `ggplot2` a bit better.